# Any good library or software for queue networks simulation?

Tags: simulation

I have been trying to make work [EZSIM](http://www-rcf.usc.edu/%7Ekhoshnev/software.html) with no luck, which is a software to build discrete event simulators in a graphical DOS environment. In this software, my simulator and many others (of the other people in the course I'm taking) don't work, but teacher's simulator (and examples of the downloaded files) does work.

So, I began to distrust of the software.

Do you know any software that resolves the same kind of problems but *really works*? It will be good if it is free, or I can download an evaluation copy or something like that.

If you don't know any software, do you know any library which might work? Preferably in C#, Ansi C, Java or Delphi.

Answer (score 2):

This may be more than what you're looking for, but [check out NS2](http://www.isi.edu/nsnam/ns/).  It's the standard for open source network simulations, and will allow you to simulate all kinds of network layer behavior.

I've also [used JUNG in the past](http://jung.sourceforge.net/).  It's very flexible, although it also doesn't offer much out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

I used [Möbius](http://www.mobius.illinois.edu/) in my computer systems analysis class.  It is free for educational use (which sounds like what you're doing).  It's a Java GUI which generates C++ code.

Comment: very cool resource.  I have had to write my own QNS/QNA stuff in the last 15 years because of the virtual death of this methodology & market:  this looks like a good substitute though.

Answer (score 0):

The [R package `queuecomputer`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/queuecomputer/index.html). `queuecomputer` is a computationally efficient method for simulating queues with arbitrary arrival and service times. There is a submitted paper on [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.02151) describing the algorithm used in the package. Examples can be found within the arXiv paper and the [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/queuecomputer/vignettes/Howto.html). A web app based on the package is available at https://ace-ebert.shinyapps.io/queue_simulator_mmk/ .